# Simplest way to create a PDF form

Tags: pdf, forms

This is about a role playing game. The 'character sheet' is a two page form, in which each player describes their character.

Currently this form is being printed and filled out with a pen. I would like to feature filling of the form before printing. It seems `hyperrf` [can do that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/218243/45581). Is there  simpler way?

---

EDIT: thanks, everyone. I was skeptical of `hyperref` because it seems like something for web links. Thus modifiable fields sounded to me like an accidental hack.

But if it is the recommended package - I'll learn it and use it. Or `eforms`.

Comment: If you would like help with something then you need to provide sufficient details so that people can reproduce your problem and so have a chance of answering your question. Please add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). This should be a compilable piece of code that is as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. Although this is not completely clear from your question, it sounds like you just want to create a PDF form? If this is the case a quick search on TeX.SX reveals questions like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398905 ...

Comment: @Andrew indeed, I was wandering if `hyperrf` is the usually suggested package or something else. The purpose of the form is to be printed, no web access needed.

Comment: The example you linked to seems pretty simple to me. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: Short answer: as far as I know, no, there is no simpler way.  The `hyperref` package provides a very simple interface to PDF forms, why doesn’t it satisfy your needs?

Comment: One could also use the `eforms` package - based on `hyperref`.