# hyperref TextField content getting cut off

Tags: hyperref

I've been handed a tex file that's being used as a template by a coworker, and his program inserts some value into a `TextField`. When the value is long, the end of the value gets cut off, as in this example:

[image]

Can I have the font-size change automatically? In PDFs generated by Adobe Acrobat, I've seen that after editing the contents of a textfield, the content is re-rendered with a font suitable to the length of the content and the size of the textfield.

If that's out of the question, is there another approach I should take?

Here's a minimal example that demonstrates the content clipping:

```tex
\documentclass[fontsize=14pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\TextField[value=foo bar baz qux, width=1cm, name=a]{}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes righto. I've added a minimum working example

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218243/pdf-form-fields-charsize-auto/218261#218261

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this by setting the charsize to 0pt (which means then "auto") and if you want also the option donotscroll. The picture shows different fillings of such a field.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\TextField[charsize=0pt,donotscroll,value=foo bar baz qux, width=1cm, name=a]{}

\TextField[charsize=0pt,donotscroll,value=foo bar baz qux, width=1cm, name=b]{}

\TextField[charsize=0pt,donotscroll,value=foo bar baz qux, width=1cm, name=c]{}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here, I start setting the text into a box, while varying the fontsize from 2pt, 2.25pt, ..., 14pt.  I find the largest size that will fit in the designated width* and then use the `charsize` option of `\TextField` to set the text box in that size.

*(approximately)

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{xcolor,pgffor}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\newcommand\AutoTextField[3][name=a]{%
  \def\fsize{2pt}%
  \foreach\z in {2,2.25,...,14}{%
    \sbox0{\fontsize{\z pt}{\z pt}\selectfont\sffamily#2}%
    \ifdim\wd0<\dimexpr#3-\z pt+ 2pt\relax\xdef\fsize{\z}\fi
  }%
  \TextField[#1, charsize=\fsize pt, value=#2, width=#3]
}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\TextField[value=foo bar baz qux, width=1cm, name=a]{OLD:}\\

\AutoTextField{foo bar baz qux}{1cm}{X:}
\AutoTextField{foo bar baz qux}{1.5cm}{X:}
\AutoTextField{foo bar baz qux}{2cm}{X:}
\AutoTextField{foo bar baz qux}{2.5cm}{X:}
\AutoTextField{foo bar baz qux}{3cm}{X:}\\

\AutoTextField{foo bar baz qux}{6cm}{X:}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

[image]